# Should I create different databases for different languages of my app?

Tags: mobile, user-expectation, mobile-application, language

So my application is meant to be equally used between those of Arabic language and English language due to its religious purposes.

I don't want my users to be confused/annoyed when they see something they can't read, so I was thinking of creating a separate database, one for those of English language and one for those of Arabic language. This will keep the posts with the Arabic language separated from those of the English language. Only the users that have their language set to English will see the English posts others have created, and the same goes for the Arabic users.

This will be good but it could stop some users from seeing some content they might've wanted to see anyways. So should I implement this?

Comment: My inclination would _not_ be to separate them; at best, tag each post with its language, and if a user only wants one language, add the language tag to the query. It also lets you easily add languages later, by just having another tag value for the new language.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two types of data for which you need to translate

1. **Static UI Messages and Texts**: You need to have one file for one language in the resource manager which contains the messages and texts in the particular language. That i.e 'Messages.en.filetype' for english, 'Messages.ar.filetype' for arabic and so on. So from the users preference you get which file is to be used for a particular login.
2. **Data input by user in forms**: The data that is dynamically entered in your site needs to have a different table, which maps the various translations of the same data into different language IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never seen/heard of a site which allows a user to choose whether to see individual level posts posted in different languages, but it's not a bad idea. Like you said, however, it could be confusing to the average user.

If you do go w/ that approach, you will need to ensure it is very clear at the top of the page/header what your methodology is. Actually wording that right might be a little bit of a challenge.. :D

Comment: Facebook is doing something like this. So you probably have seen something like this.